# INNER JOIN on Eloquent result sets in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, inner-join

I want to find a match between a database result set of a user and result sets of friends.
First I'm making a call to the database to get the ids of the user items:

```
$user_simp_items = Item::select('simp_id')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

Then I loop through the friends and make a call to get their item ids:

```
$friend_simp_items = Item::select('simp_id')->where('user_id', $friend_id)->get();
```

To find the matching ids I want to perform an INNER JOIN on the result sets. How do I do this in Laravel?

I'd like to do something like inner_join($user_simp_items, $friend_simp_items) and get the result set with only the matching items.

Comment: Which version you can use for laravel.

Comment: If those two tables are in relation the use either [Inner Join Clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Will this also work on a query that has been finished already? Because I need to do the queries in different places, I can't write it in one query so I have to join the resulting collections

Comment: You could always eager load a "friends" method?  This would simplify your first query at the expense of a little extra code in your model?  That way calling your $user_simp_items will always give you access to the friends as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the toArray Eloquent method and then did an array_filter to get the intersecting elements.